JPEG decoder colour issue - suspect DC coefficient/Huffman decoding is the cause
I'm trying to build a JPEG decoder, and I'm testing it on a greyscale image to keep things simple:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grayscale_%28182824419%29.jpeg
The code works OK, but the image is too dark, so I suspect there's an issue with the DC coefficients (as  I understand it, the AC coefficients don't affect overall brightness, just the patterns that you see).
Details of what I tried on the next page.
I looked at the first 8x8 MCU, and compared its overall brightness to a standard decoder in Python (matplotlib.image imread):

The first quantization coefficient I see is 4
If I look at the MCU:

The first thing here is 6 binary 1s followed by a zero.  Looking that up in the DC Huffman table, this appears to correspond to the number 8 (i.e. the first DC coefficient is 8 bits long).
The next eight bits seem to represent the number 241


Therefore I thought the first DC coefficient should be 241*4 (multiplying by the quantization coefficient)
To determine overall brightness from this coefficient, we then need to divide by 8 (based on my reading of A.3.3 of the JPEG ITU, page 27, because Cv and Cu are both 1/sqrt(2) )

We therefore arrive at a brightness of 241*4/8=120.5, which I presume is out of 255.
If I compare to matplotlib.image, the average brightness of the top left 8x8 pixels is 248.515625.
What am I doing wrong?  Why is my average brightness for the top left 8x8 pixels so dark compared to matplotlib?
Additional questions:

How does matplotlib.image get this figure, which appears to have 64ths in it?  As I understand it, the DC coefficient should be an integer, and then we divide by 8 to get average brightness, not 64.  So the smallest fraction we have should be 8ths not 64ths?
I notice that the Huffman table for DC coefficients 'appears' suboptimal.  i.e. the value 9 is encoded by 11111110 (7 1s and a zero) when it could just have been encoded by 7 1s, saving a bit.

Why is this?  Is it to break up the sequence of 1s so it doesn't look like we've reached the end of a block?  Or is there a mistake in the way I have decoded the DC Huffman table?

I think the problem with your DC greyscale component is that you have forgotten to add back the +128 bias. 120.5 + 128 = 248.5. Same as Python. Try it and see. I also suspect  rounding effects on quantised coefficients explain the 1/64 th deviation on the sum.


I notice that the Huffman table for DC coefficients 'appears' suboptimal. i.e. the value 9 is encoded by 11111110 (7 1s and a zero) when it could just have been encoded by 7 1s, saving a bit.

There is a sample huffman table in the JPEG standard that some encoders use (the same goes with PNG). An optimal huffman table requires scanning the DCT coefficients twice. In ye olde days the DCT was time consuming so people did it in integer and did a single scan of the data. Now the slowest part of JPEG is usually reading and writing the data.

How does matplotlib.image get this figure, which appears to have 64ths in it? As I understand it, the DC coefficient should be an integer, and then we divide by 8 to get average brightness, not 64. So the smallest fraction we have should be 8ths not 64ths?

The DCT coefficients are mathematically real numbers. It is common to implement the DCT using scaled integers. With a 32-bit integer, you might shift everything by 16 and use the low order 16 bits as fraction. This method gave a greater rounding error than using 8-byte floating point values but was faster.
As for darkness, as others mention, it sounds like you have not subtracted 128 from your color values after the DCT.
